# list to string using "".join() - issues with passing a list of lists of strings

Tags: python, string, list, shuffle

I feel like maybe this is an issue with using "".join() with a list of lists of strings instead of a list of strings, but haven't found an answer.

Maybe it's something else that I am missing.

I hope my notes show what I have been trying (to take a list of strings turn them into a str and append 'scramble' with that string)

```
# SCRAMBLE WORD/PHRASE
# IMPORTS
import random

# VARIABLES
test_words_list = ["dark", "happy holidays", "computer", "I like pie", "dogs love pizza"]

# FUNCTIONS
#function too big? cut down into smaller? or too small to be worth it?

def scramble_string(string, seperate_words = False):
  scramble = ""
  if seperate_words == False:
    """Remove spaces & scramble all letters together into one string"""
    words_list = string.split(" ")          # removes whitespace (list)
    print(f"letters_list= {words_list}")
    for word_str in words_list:
      word_letter_list = [letter for letter in word_str]
      print(f"word_letters_list = {word_letter_list}")
      random.shuffle(word_letter_list)
      print(f"After shuffle word_letters_list = {word_letter_list}")
      word_letter_str = "".join(word_letter_list)
      print(f"word_letter_str = {word_letter_str}")
      scramble += word_letter_str
      print(f"scramble = {scramble}")
    return scramble
  else:
    """scramble letters in words without mixing letters from different words.
    List words in same order with space between, but with letters scrambled"""
    scrambled_list = []
    words_list = string.split()                      # passed string into list of strings
    print(f"words_list = {words_list}")
    for word_str in words_list:
      letters_list = [letter for letter in word_str]
      print(f"letters_list = {letters_list}")
      random.shuffle(letters_list)
      print(f"After shuffle letters_list = {letters_list}")
      scrambled_list.append(letters_list)            # list of lists
      print(f"scrambled_list = {scrambled_list}")

      # vv PROBLEM vv
      scrambled_str = "".join(scrambled_list)  #"sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"
      scramble += scrambled_str
      #scramble = ''.join(str(scrambled_list)[1:-1]) # makes scramble a list???
      print(f"scramble = {scramble}")
  return scramble

# Tests

#print(scramble_string(test_words_list[1]))          # WORKS (returned = "hyppahadsilyo")
print(scramble_string(test_words_list[-1], True))    # returns =
```

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of what this *should* do and what it is doing instead?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: What do you need the intermediate `scrambled_list` for?

Comment: What I was expecting was a string (ideally something like "sdog eovl zapzi"). What I was getting was an error ("sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found") or in a different attempt a list of strings.

Comment: @deceze I see now I could have avoided this issue if I had been neater in my changes and not ended up with both scrambled_list and word_letter_list (as a second is unecessary). Thank you, I need to work on that (both the messy editing and not checking for a redundancy causing my issues).

Comment: Removed the `random` tag since your problem has nothing to do with the shuffled nature of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your list of list of string to list of string first. I did that at this line.

```
scrambled_list.append("".join(letters_list))            # list of lists
```

Instead of appending list of strings to a list, I am combining that list of letters to form a word and appending that scrambled word to the `scrambled_list`.

```
import random

# VARIABLES
test_words_list = ["dark", "happy holidays", "computer", "I like pie", "dogs love pizza"]

# FUNCTIONS
#function too big? cut down into smaller? or too small to be worth it?

def scramble_string(string, seperate_words = False):
    scramble = ""
    if seperate_words == False:
        """Remove spaces & scramble all letters together into one string"""
        words_list = string.split(" ")        # removes whitespace (list)
        print(f"letters_list= {words_list}")
        for word_str in words_list:
            word_letter_list = [letter for letter in word_str]
            print(f"word_letters_list = {word_letter_list}")
            random.shuffle(word_letter_list)
            print(f"After shuffle word_letters_list = {word_letter_list}")
            word_letter_str = "".join(word_letter_list)
            print(f"word_letter_str = {word_letter_str}")
            scramble += word_letter_str
            print(f"scramble = {scramble}")
        return scramble
    else:
        """scramble letters in words without mixing letters from different words.
        List words in same order with space between, but with letters scrambled"""
        scrambled_list = []
        words_list = string.split()                   # passed string into list of strings
        print(f"words_list = {words_list}")
        for word_str in words_list:
            letters_list = [letter for letter in word_str]
            print(f"letters_list = {letters_list}")
            random.shuffle(letters_list)
            print(f"After shuffle letters_list = {letters_list}")
            scrambled_list.append("".join(letters_list))            # list of lists
            print(f"scrambled_list = {scrambled_list}")

        # vv PROBLEM vv
        scrambled_str = "".join(scrambled_list)  #"sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"
        scramble += scrambled_str
        #scramble = ''.join(str(scrambled_list)[1:-1]) # makes scramble a list???
        print(f"scramble = {scramble}")
    return scramble

# Tests

# print(scramble_string(test_words_list[1]))          # WORKS (returned = "hyppahadsilyo")
print(scramble_string(test_words_list[-1], True))
```

Comment: Thanks. I will remember that "".join() doesn't work with nested lists of strings.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, `.join` works with list of strings, but not with list of list of strings.

Comment: Yes, at first I thought it would work for a list of lists of strings. Then I got the error and couldn't find answers on if that was indeed the problem (couldn't find other causes either and got stuck - thanks for your help).

Answer (score 0):

This is the function now working correctly (with basic improvements) for anyone with a similar issue in the future.

```
# SCRAMBLE WORD/PHRASE
# IMPORTS
import random

# VARIABLES
test_words_list = ["dark", "happy holidays", "computer", "I like pie", "dogs love pizza"]

# FUNCTIONS

def scramble_string(string: str, seperate_words = False) -> str:
  string = string.lower()
  scramble = ""
  if seperate_words == False:
    """Remove spaces & scramble all letters together into one string"""
    words_list = string.split(" ")          
    for word_str in words_list:
      word_letter_list = [letter for letter in word_str]    # list of letter in word for each word in words_list
      random.shuffle(word_letter_list)
      scrambled_word_str = "".join(word_letter_list)
      scramble += scrambled_word_str
  else:
    """scramble letters in words WITHOUT mixing letters from different words.
    List scrambled words in orginal order (with space between)"""
    words_list = string.split()
    for word in words_list:
      scrambled_list = [letter for letter in word]
      random.shuffle(scrambled_list)
      scrambled_str = "".join(scrambled_list)
      scrambled_str += " "                           # Add space between words in string
      scramble += scrambled_str
  return scramble

# Tests
print(scramble_string(test_words_list[-2]))           # WORKS (returned = "hyppahadsilyo")
print(scramble_string(test_words_list[-1], True))    # WORKS (returned = "sdog eovl zapzi")

# Working Notes (to track & learn from mistakes)
# Error SOURCE: scrambled_list.append(letters_list)   
# Failed Solution(makes scramble a list): scramble = ''.join(str(scrambled_list)[1:-1])  
# Soultion(Error: "sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found") scrambled_list.append("".join(letters_list))
# Error RESOLVED (list of lists of strings given to "".join): scrambled_str = "".join(scrambled_list)
```